# Why is there gasoline in my generator's crankcase?

Tags: repair

Briggs & Stratton portable generator blowing white smoke.  when checking the oil level gas poured out.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: How did you check the oil?

Comment: That's a pretty interpretative edit of the title... (Probably accurate, but something of a leap)

Comment: It is all speculation until the OP posts MORE details.  The statement in the "question"  taken at face value would seam to be saying that when the oil dipstick was unscrewed that gas came out of the opening, that would suggest gas in the crankcase. White smoke, bad rings. Bad rings, fuel getting in crankcase. ??

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of the carburetor is a bowl and inside is a float-actuated valve.  Gas is gravity fed from the tank to the bowl, and when the bowl fills up, the valve is supposed to close off flow from the tank.  When that fails, gas can continue through the carburetor and into the idle engine, and eventually make its way into the oil at the bottom of the crankcase.

You will need to thoroughly clean the carb, and I'd recommend installing an inline fuel cut-off valve.  Lastly, you'll want to change the oil.